# How do I move a database from one server to another in PgSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to move a database from my old server to a new server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The right answer to this question depends a lot of the size of your database. but dumprestore is most like the correct answer.

Comment: What is the size of your database? How big downtime window you can have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just [pipe](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/migration.html) a dump from the old server into the new one:

```
pg_dump -h 172.26.76.100 -p 5432 -U username your_db | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U username your_db
```

Replace the ip addresses and there you go. If you're using different versions of PostgreSQL, make sure you use **pg_dump** and **psql** from the latest version.

Comment: pg_dumpall will get everything.  He should make sure he uses roles that are superusers to get everything.

Answer (score 2):

Dump it on the first server and restore it on the second, using either the command line tools or something loke pgAdmin.