# Import CSV into SQL Server 2008 R2 Automatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

How can I have SQL Server Import csv data from a folder automatically?

I have a folder named RawData on the root drive that a system is currently pushing a csv file to, so anytime there's a new file SQL Server should import it.

Comment: You can implement an SSIS package as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315732/how-can-i-a-sql-server-agent-job-if-a-file-exists-in-a-server-folder) thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look here to get ideas about ways to import csv files into SQLServer :
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12

SSIS seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you!!! SSIS is what I'm currently using but how I can make that run automatically?

Comment: You can schedule jobs : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/

Comment: I am not sure you can pool automatically the directory and trigger SSIS when a new file comes in...

Comment: There are plenty of ways to import files.. question is how to automate the import process. Above link does not answer that question.

Comment: @Mayank: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server