# SQL Server : bulk insert of csv file - I need to exclude quote marks

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm using SQL Server Bulk Insert to import a `.csv` file but my `.csv` has double quotation marks enclosing text fields. Is it possible to remove the quote marks whilst importing the data?

Comment: Double quotes are used to enclose text that might contain commas that shouldn't be considered a separating value. If you do remove them, make sure the commas are still treated correctly.

Comment: `FIELDTERMINATOR ='","'` is what you are looking for I think. However, you will be left with the first and last column having a quote in it. You can fix this with `REPLACE()` function after you bring the data into a `TEMP TABLE` prior to inserting it into your `DB Table`or use a `FORMAT FILE` with your `BULK INSERT` to avoid this all together. They can be annoying though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25732545/6167855

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think a Format File may be the answer but what parameters would I set in the file to exclude the quotes.

Comment: [Create a Format File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx), or, [another article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx), and lastly, the answer I linked above was for a quoted field... just like yours

Comment: Yes, thanks, I didn't see the link! I'll give that a go.

Comment: This answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803705/79485