# Remove double quotes from csv file while inserting data into table using bulk collect in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from .csv file(test_abcd.csv), below is the file data:

[image]

It is having 2 rows and a header.
below is the table structure:
A char(10),
B char(10),
C char(10),
D char(10),
E char(10),
F char(10),
G char(10),
H char(10)

below is bulk insert command:

```
bulk insert TEST_ABCD
from 'C:\path\TEST_ABCD.csv'
with
    (   datafiletype = 'char',
        fieldterminator = ',',
        rowterminator = '\n',
        formatfile='C:\path\newFormat.fmt',
        firstrow = 2
    );
```

and below is format file:

```
14.0
```

17
1       SQLCHAR       0       0       """                      0     dummy1             ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      1     A             ""
3       SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy2             ""
4       SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      2     B             ""
5       SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy3             ""
6       SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      3     C             ""
7       SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy4             ""
8       SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      4     D             ""
9       SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy5             ""
10      SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      5     E             ""
11      SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy6             ""
12      SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      6     F             ""
13      SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy7             ""
14      SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      7     G             ""
15      SQLCHAR       0       0       ",""                     0     dummy8             ""
16      SQLCHAR       0       50      """                      8     H             ""
17      SQLCHAR       0       0       "\r\n"                    0     dummy9             ""

command executes successfully but only one is getting inserting will null values.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
```

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

and if I open test_abcd.csv file in notepad++ then it is showing like below:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
```

"""1""","""2""","""3""","""4""","""5""","""6""","""7""","""8"""
"""21""","""22""","""23""","""24""","""25""","""26""","""27""","""28"""

How can I change or update my format file so I can insert proper data of csv into table.

I am using sql server 2019 developer edition

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2017 added support for [CSV files and quoted fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#input-file-format-options). There's no need for a format file any more.

You can load a CSV file with fields quoted using double quotes simply by adding `WITH ( FORMAT = 'CSV')`  :

```
bulk insert TEST_ABCD
from 'C:\path\TEST_ABCD.csv'
with (  
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        firstrow = 2
     );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but its not helping, its loading data with quotes.