# C# Store Unknown Amount of Elements in SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, sqlcommand

I am currently reading and parsing 10 different file(.txt, .csv), each file has a different number of columns.

Here is a sample from one file:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into " + table_name + " VALUES('"+data_from_file[0]+"', '" + data_from_file[1] + "', '" + data_from_file[2] + "', '" + data_from_file[3] + "', '" + data_from_file[4] + "','" + data_from_file[5] + "', '" + data_from_file[6] + "', '" + data_from_file[7] + "', '" + data_from_file[8] + "', '" + data_from_file[9] + "');", connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This file has a total of 10 columns that gets inserted into its own table. If I do it like this for the 10 files, I would have 10 different if/else if statements. And to me that sounds like bad way of doing this. Is there a way to iterate through the array and insert each element? I have been looking for ways to do it, but cannot find a proper solution for my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server

Comment: Are you able to integrate Entity Framework into this project? for a little bit of extra leg work, EF would make things look a whole lot cleaner.. You could create seperate classes for the 10 different types you have, then create a file reader class of some sort  to create arrays of these new entities and let EF Data Context take care of the inserting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most classical way would be to `iterate` and append to a `string` and then execute:

```
string command = "insert into " + table_name + " VALUES(";

foreach(string data in data_from_file)
{
    command += "'" + data + "',";
}
command = command.TrimEnd(','); // remove the last extra ','
command += ");";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

### However, I recommend that you have a look at [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) for Large Insert Queries.

Comment: Thank you very much fo the help. Your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

First you iterate over your collection, and then you insert every entry from the collection into the database.

```
            foreach (var oneColumn in data)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES(" + oneColumn + ")");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```