# SQL server express import CSV to table

Tags: database, sql-server-express

Hi I know how to import CSV into the table that I have created, by using the GUI way as below link:

```
https://host4asp.net/import-csv-file-using-sql-server-management-studio/
```

But my boss want me to do with query, I search around the internet but I did't get the solution, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV file into SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
BULK INSERT Fundamental.dbo.Stock_Table
    FROM 'C:/Dummy Data.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
GO
```