# Import CSV file into database(sql) via BULK INSERT or LOAD DATA

Tags: sql-server, csv, coldfusion, azure-sql-database, coldfusion-11

Want to insert some data into SQL. I am using cfquery tag to manipulate SQL queries.

This is my first try:

```
<body>
    <cfquery NAME="Insert" DATASOURCE="#app.dsn#">
        LOAD DATA INFILE "F:\app\new.csv"
        INTO TABLE FROM CSVIMP
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
    </cfquery> 
    <output>
        <CFQUERY NAME="Show" DATASOURCE="#app.dsn#">
            SELECT * FROM CSVIMP
        </CFQUERY>
        #Show#
    </output>
    </body>
```

And because this was not working I give it a shoot with BULK INSERT.
My second try:

```
<body>
<cfquery NAME="Insert" DATASOURCE="#app.dsn#">
    BULK INSERT CSVIMP FROM ‘F:\app\new.csv’
    WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘,’, ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’)
</cfquery> 
<output>
    <CFQUERY NAME="Show" DATASOURCE="#app.dsn#">
        SELECT * FROM CSVIMP
    </CFQUERY>
    #Show#
</output>
</body>
```

But even this is not working.
It's not giving me any kind of error, just the values from csv is not inserted in MySQL.

The CSV is like this:
new.csv:

```
Test,Test2
Test3,Test4
```

What I'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: it's F:, forgot to edit that

Comment: @Drew
Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near 'LOCAL'.

Comment: @Drew The default was without LOCAL and it was not giving me any error. Now i added LOCAL and it gives me error, so I guess it's not working either.

The slashes are correct.

Comment: How many databases do you have?  You say the rows are not being inserted into mySql and you show us a sql server error message.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have only 1 DB with many tables, but I double checked, so the tabels and db is set correctly.
Beside, if the table would be spelled wrong, then the ColdFusion would give me error that it can't connect to DB.

Comment: Try using UNC path. (Even if local or using a mapped drive, I found this to work better.) To determine if a row is giving you a problem, use the "errorfile" property. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15243801/693068

Comment: @Drew it's MySQL server

Comment: @Drew yes, this was just a typo when i make this post.

Comment: @JamesMoberg I tried that and it's now working. It doesn't give me any error, but the errorfile is not existing at all.

Comment: Is it maybe, bacause i've got multiple columns in table ?

Comment: How is the datasource app.dns configured? From the error (some comments above) it seems configured to use jdbc driver for sqlserver.

Comment: @Aris2World Yes, I use Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server, the how's and why's can be found here:
https://www.hass.de/content/coldfusion-10-how-configure-data-sources-microsoft-jdbc-driver-40-sql-server

Comment: @Drew yes, I made mistake before, I did a research and I am using Azure SQL. Apologize for misinformation

Comment: No problem let me delete a bunch of my comments above then

Comment: Maybe no rows are imported for an invalid data or format. I suggest you to create an error file as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to put it in a loop.

```
<cfloop query="csv_query">
                <cfquery datasource="#app.dsn#">
                    INSERT INTO CSVIMP (
                        Test1,
                        Test2
                    ) VALUES (
                        '#csv_query.column_1#',
                        '#csv_query.column_2#'
                    )
                </cfquery>
        </cfloop>
```

Comment: -1. This does not answer the original question, which is about bulk loading tools. Plus the question itself is very unclear. The text says the database used is MySQL, yet some of the syntax, question tags and error message are for SQL Server.