# SQL Server 2012: update data from CSV based on primary keys

Tags: sql-server, csv

So I have this table in my database. We'll say it's called `users`.

```
UserID   UserName   UserDescription
-----------------------------------
1        test1      Test User #1
2        test2      Test User #2
3        test3      Test User #3
4        test4      Test User #4
5        test5      Test User #5
```

And I have this CSV file:

```
1,"Harry Potter"
4,"Hermione Granger"
3,"Ron Weasley"
```

What I want is to update the table from the CSV file. Here's the result I'm looking for:

```
UserID   UserName   UserDescription
-----------------------------------
1        test1      Harry Potter
2        test2      Test User #2
3        test3      Ron Weasley
4        test4      Hermione Granger
5        test5      Test User #5
```

Without having to write a program to do this, is there a way to accomplish this kind of update from the CSV file?

Basically I want to do something like what you can do in the Import Data wizard - map the CSV columns to their respective database columns - but to have the database *update* any columns where the primary key in the database matches the assigned column in the CSV file.

(SQL Server 2012)

Comment: Can't you load it to a temp table and then join and update?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: I'm a fan of `OPENROWSET` (see @ron-smith's anwer). I prefer it to importing data to a temp table. If anyone is interested: [Getting Started With OPENROWSET and the BULK Rowset Provider](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2016/01/Openrowset-Bulk-Rowset-Provider-Part-2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. **Import the CSV into a temporary table.**

   Related question for details: *[Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15242757/87698)*.
2. **Update the main table with the data from the temporary table.**

   Related question for details: *[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334712/87698)*

   Code example:

   ```
   UPDATE users
      SET users.UserDescription = #import.UserDescription
     FROM users 
          INNER JOIN #import ON users.UserID = #import.UserID
   ```

Comment: Didn't think of this, turns out to be the simplest way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [openrowset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to access your csv file in SQL Server. This example assumes you have matching column names in your table and csv file. You can adjust file name, directory, and column names as necessary:

```
update users
    set users.UserDescription = csv.UserDescription
    from users
        inner join openrowset('MSDASQL',
            'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}',
            'select * from C:\YourCSV.csv') as csv
            on csv.UserID = users.UserID
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that the file resides on the SQL server? Assume I don't have write access to put arbitrary CSV files on the server that runs SQL Server.