# I was given a csv with thousands of IDs in a csv and need to use these IDs for a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

In the past when I was given a csv there would be only a few thousand rows so I would just create a temporary table and then insert the needed values into the table.  The problem here is that I was given a csv this time with over 80,000 rows and there is a maximum allowed number of inserting 1000 row values.  In the past with a few thousand I would just do this 3 or 4 times and then union them to create a master temporary table.  What can I do to get these csv IDs into my SQL server?  Also I included what I was doing before to be clear.  Also to note, I have *limited access*.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**  Limited access means that I don't have permission to use the bulk load statement.  I hoping there was a around that.  If not, I will have to just explain the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE ##Test(ID BIGINT);

INSERT INTO ##Test
VALUES
(21477217322),
(21479276022),
(21478037922)
;
```

Comment: Import the CSV- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV file into SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Comment: I do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.  I was hoping there was a way around it.  I think this is something that I just need to tell them I can't do with my current access so give me more access or have someone else do it.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need bulk load permissions for the answer that has been given. You just need insert permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a table valued constructor. You can instead use UNION ALL and then there is no limitation. Just have your csv build you a string that looks like this.

```
SELECT 21477217322 UNION ALL
SELECT 21479276022 UNION ALL
SELECT 21478037922
```

Or an even simpler solution would be to use the data import tool and not do this manually.

Comment: I tried to use the data import but it said my access was too limited.  Thanks.

Comment: Well if you are restricted from importing data there may well be a reason for that. I would get with your dba and ask about getting access for this type of thing so you can do your job.

Comment: Haha.  Yeah.  That looks to be the case.  I just thought I would throw out a hail mary to stack overflow.  Appreciate the response.