# Importing CSV to SQL using Powershell getting the whole object instead of each column

Tags: powershell

I've got a fairly simple csv with 3 columns that I would like to import into SQL using powershell. I thought I it working except I'm literally getting the whole line object in each column in SQL rather than each column from the csv file. Just to complicate matters I'm also adding in an extra guid field into SQL that isn't in the csv but that seems to be the only column that's actually working.

Powershell

```
  Import-CSV D:\sample.csv | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Sqlcmd `
 -Database $DbName -ServerInstance $ServerName -OutputSqlErrors $true `
 -Query "insert into $DbTable ([item],[lob],[cc],[file_import_guid]) VALUES ('$_.Item','$_.LOB','$_.CC','$ImportGUID')"
 }
```

and my sample csv is simply

```
Item,LOB,CC
0029544090511,LOBJ17_0003559,PCC
0029544090511,LOBJ17_0003560,PCC
```

Therefore I expected each column to import but instead I got this in SQL which was unexpected.

```
item    lob cc  file_import_guid
@{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003559; CC=PCC}.Item  @{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003559; CC=PCC}.LOB   @{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003559; CC=PCC}.CC    7550d245-32b9-447a-bcfa-bbe6e7e22fd8
@{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003560; CC=PCC}.Item  @{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003560; CC=PCC}.LOB   @{Item=0029544090511; LOB=LOBJ17_0003560; CC=PCC}.CC    7550d245-32b9-447a-bcfa-bbe6e7e22fd8
```

The guid seems to be working fine so its something in the object loop. I tried changing to a simple foreach loop but get the same result. When I try and check my data with a write-host command it looks fine (on screen at least)

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Import-CSV D:\sample.csv | ForEach-Object {write-host $_.Item $_.LOB $_.CC $ImportGUID}
0029544090511 LOBJ17_0003559 PCC e55019b0-d783-4fd8-9dda-0f409323e8bc
0029544090511 LOBJ17_0003560 PCC e55019b0-d783-4fd8-9dda-0f409323e8bc
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change last part of the SQL statement to `VALUES ('$($_.Item)','$($_.LOB)','$($_.CC)','$($ImportGUID)')`

Comment: Can we not help other people opening themselves up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? Pretty please? If you must insert data like this, please use prepared statements.

Comment: Have you looked into [bulk-importing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server) the CSV? See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15242757/1630171).

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen - Thanks a lot that's exactly what I needed its working now.