# SSMS: Merge two Excel sheets into a single SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have two Excel sheets, one containing customer information :

```
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Fname | Lname | Birth | Gender |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

and a second one with transaction logs formatted as follows :

```
+------+--------+
| Date | Amount |
+------+--------+
```

My SQL table is empty and has the following fields :

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| ID | First Name | Last Name | Gender | Birth | Spent | Date |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+------+
```

I'm looking for a way to merge the two sheets and transfer the data into the table but cannot figure out an efficient way to do it.

Comment: How many records? It's a one shot activity or a periodic one?

Comment: How are you matching the records in the first sheet to the second? There doesn't appear to be anything to link the two together.

Comment: What is joining column?

Comment: @etsa Both sheets contain 7 rows, one for each individual sale. They are randomly dated as I only wanted to try and "reassemble" the table with them as an exercise.

Comment: @Aidan the only similiraity is the placement in the sheets.
Sale 1 corresponds to customer 1, sale 2 is customer 2's etc..

Comment: @ilomax I would suggest that each user is given a CustomerID, and that an ID is applied to each transaction. Otherwise you have to create a duplicate customer record every time someone makes a new transaction. Depending on the order of the rows to match up is super not recommended.

Comment: @Aidan I get what you mean. As I said above, my goal was to see if I could fill a table with data contained on several sheets. Now that you mention it, it is slightly illogical and useless not to have any matching criteria.
I just overthought the thing and maybe figured something that is very unlikely to happen in a real-life professional scenario.

Comment: @ilomax Oh, OK, you're just messing around to see if it can be done, rather than implementing this actual structure somewhere. I wouldn't be too worried about it, if I were you, just keep it in mind for the future. As for your question, you're probably looking for something like BULK INSERT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

Comment: @Aidan I've already used `BULK INSERT` to transfer data from a .txt. SSMS has a wizard which can be used to create a table directly from an Excel sheet. But I'm indeed just playing around, trying to get as familiar and at-ease as possible with SQL Server and the language before I actually get to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BULK INSERT` to insert the data from the excel files into a table. What i would recommend you do is create 2 temporary tables; `#Customers` and `#Transactions`. Insert your customers file data into `#Customers`, your transaction data into `#Transactions`.

Then, insert data into your `CustomersAndTransactions` table by selecting your data from the two temporary tables using a join.

You can read up on `BULK INSERT` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

There are also plenty of good questions about `BULK INSERT` on StackOverflow already, such as this one which should help you avoid a few problems: [Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)