# SQL Server 2014: errors 0xc02020f4 when loading CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv

I try to load a big CSV file (10M lines, 100 columns!) into a SQL Server 2014 DB .

In input, I have:

- a CSV file, generated by an external company with these parameters 
  (impossible to make it use other settings)

· code page ISO-8859-15 (Latin 9)

· field delimiter: ;

· text delimiter: "

· DOS/Windows end of lines (CRLF)

- SQL "CREATE TABLE" command with right types and lengths for each column

When I try to populate this table with import wizard, I've many 0xc02020f4 errors:
"The column "xxx" cannot be processed because more than one code page (28605 and 1252) are specified for it. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)"

How can I deal with this problem ?

Should I create a DB or table with special collation ?

The table has 100 columns, I'd like to get a solution at higher level than column... ;o)

Thanks by advance.
Regards,
Steph.

Comment: Did you try to import it using BULK INSERT? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server
I usually had problems with Import and Export Wizard, but BULK INSERT worked.

Comment: I have double quote as char string qualifier. Impossible to specify that with BULK INSERT command

Answer (score 1):

In the Import Export Wizard make sure you change the Code Page to 1252 (ANSI - Latin 1) instead of ISO-8859-15 (Latin 9).