# Is it possible to Import a csv-file to a SQLite table via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, csv

At the moment iv managed to use commands like `SELECT * FROM` via functions in Node.js to do things in my SQLite database but i havent been able to use commands like:

```
.import
.mode CSV
.help
```

are they not supported ?
if not is there a "simple" solution to this or does it involve alot of code, frameworks etc?

As far as iv found out and with alot of testing i havent found any post
or way to use node.js to import a local csv-file to SQLite

(even if the purpose why i would do this is vague and not just populate the database via its CLI or a SQLite database manager software, its for a project)

Comment: What you're referencing in your question are "*dot commands*"; they are specific to the [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) and are not available for use in a traditional query interface. The core of your question being "How do I import a CSV to SQLite using Node.js" is a duplicate of [Using CSV file in node-sqlite3 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751259/using-csv-file-in-node-sqlite3-package) (among many others on this site - please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]); I'm voting to close as such.

Comment: editted it thx :)