# Automatically add data from CSV to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

SAP generates data twice a day and stores that data to a file server to `.CSV` files. Always create a new table. I need to automatically put these data into the SQL Server database. Will anyone please advise me?

Thank you

Comment: hope this helps-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a `SSIS package` with a `Foreach Loop Container` within it that will load all the existing files from a predefined path to your table in `SQL Server` database.
You can then delete or move the elaborated files to another folder.

You then schedule the execution of this package with `SQL Server Agent job` to run when you want, once or twice a day.

Here you fine the complete example of creating such a package:
[Loop through Flat Files in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)