# How to update/insert data into the table from pipe separated .csv file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have imported data from .csv file to temp table and it is like

```
ID          DEPARTMENT      DESIGNATION       LOCATION     REGION       STATE

Test19768   Barclays|Citi Bank|Ireland      developer   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

and have to update/insert in EMp table like

```
ID          DEPARTMENT      DESIGNATION   LOCATION        REGION        STATE
Test19768   Barclays        developer       NULL            NULL        NULL
Test19768   Citi Bank|      NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL
Test19768   Ireland         NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL
```

Need to insert multiple pipe separated value for each user ID. we can't use STRING_SPLIT as we have version 14.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
BULK INSERT TempTable
    FROM 'C:\CSVData\your.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\ErrorRows.csv',
        TABLOCK
    )
```

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Comment: FIELDTERMINATOR  is comma by actual data is pipe separated and hence need to split that data and insert into another table