# Convert Excel to CSV then expot these data to sql table using

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-csv

I have data in excel file and I need to convert the excel file to CSV file then insert these data into sql table.

Please, how can I do it ?

Do have any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Comment: One idea, save the file as a CSV using Save As in Excel. Then use SSIS, BCP or `BULK INSERT`. What have you tried so far, and where have you got stuck? This is far to broad as it is, Stack Overflow is for asking (specific) coding questions not for "how to guides". Show us what problems you're having and we can help you fix those.

Comment: Thank you Larnu, but i sthere any possibility to get the CSV automatically no tmanually because this file needs to be generated always not one time after any modification of data(very frequent )

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with the [SQL Spreads Excel Add-In](https://sqlspreads.com/). It allows you to use Excel to update and manage the data in any SQL Server table. 
You can [download a trial here](https://sqlspreads.com/download-sql-spreads/).

Disclaimer: I'm the founder.