# How do I create an API and add data via a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, rest, api

I'm trying to build an API for a react project and I'm unsure of how to build an API.

I have a CSV file with all the data.

I've used api-platform via PHP but every time I try to input the CSV into the tables in Sequel Pro it crashes.

I'm now thinking of using node.js.

Very confused as to which technology to use and the best approach to my problem.

Looked at many articles and tutorials that have helped build a basic RESTful API however none of them address how to add a CSV file into the tables or database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal recommendation when building an RESTful API in Node.js is to use [express.js](https://expressjs.com/). Easy to get started with and has many plugins.

Other possible frameworks that I can think of right now:

- [hapi.js](https://hapijs.com/)
- [koa.js](https://koajs.com/)

For reading and writing CSV-files, take a look at [this article](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-with-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

I think python can handle CSV files better. You can create API using Django.