# Question about excel columns csv file how to combine columns

Tags: excel, csv

I got a quick question I got a column like this
the players name and the percentage of matches won

```
     Rank
          Country
                       Name
                                   Matches                 Won %
       1    ESP ESP Rafael Nadal    89.06%
       2    SRB SRB Novak Djokovic  83.82%
       3    SUI SUI Roger Federer   83.61%
       4    RUS RUS Daniil Medvedev 73.75%
       5    AUT AUT Dominic Thiem   72.73%
       6    GRE GRE Stefanos Tsitsipas  67.95%
       7    JPN JPN Kei Nishikori   67.44%
```

and I got another data like this  ACES PERCENTAGE

```
    Rank
      Country
         Name
          Ace %
       1    USA USA John Isner  26.97%
       2    CRO CRO Ivo Karlovic    25.47%
       3    USA USA Reilly Opelka   24.81%
       4    CAN CAN Milos Raonic    24.63%
     5  USA USA Sam Querrey 20.75%
    6   AUS AUS Nick Kyrgios    20.73%
     7  RSA RSA Kevin Anderson  17.82%
    8   KAZ KAZ Alexander Bublik    17.06%
   9    FRA FRA Jo Wilfried Tsonga  14.29%
   ---------------------------------------
   85 ESP  ESP RAFAEL NADAL       6.85%
```

My question is can I make my two tables align so for example I want to have
my data based on matches won
So I have for example

```
                 Rank Country  Name          Matches%    Aces %
                 1    ESP      RAFAEL NADAL   89.06%    6.85%
```

Like this for all the player

Comment: you can import and customize data. Refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server
after import use "||" to combine columns

Comment: Import both and use vlookup on name to get the value you want from one table into the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment above that it would be easiest to import both and to then use XLOOKUP() to add the Aces % column to the first set of data. If you import the first data set to Sheet1 and the second data set to Sheet2 and both have the rank in Column A , your XLOOKUP() in Sheet 1 Column E would look something like:

```
XLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:A, Sheet2!D:D)
```

Comment: yeah the only thing is the rank for sheet a is based on matches won, and rank in B is based on percent aces

Comment: is there a way to have my ranking based on matches won but put the aces data which corresponds to each player.

Comment: Sure. If County is only used once in the list you can use that, or it team names are consistent between the two sheets you can search based on the name column. If team name is in Col C, it would look like:

XLOOKUP(C2, Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!D:D)